# How to create a rolling total field?

Tags: sql, window-functions

I'm trying to create a rolling total of the number of orders placed by a customer within a specific time period, ordered by date.

I have tried to use the partition function but the below query doesn't yield the correct results. Any help would be appreciated

```
select 
    CustomerID
    , Order ID
    , COUNT(OrderID) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY OrderDate) RunningOrderCount
from #existingtable
```

I want the results to be a table of all the customer ID's, all their corresponding order ID's and then a field with the order count eg...

```
CustomerID    OrderID   OrderCount
1234          5675      1
1234          5676      2
1234          5677      3
1234          5678      4
1234          5679      5
```

Comment: Are you sure that you need it? How will you use this `OrderCount`? Also, imagine that you may need to correct data or remove an old order, this would corrupt all data.

Comment: using microsoft sql server
I definitely need it, I want to use it within another query to only look at customers first order from that table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your are looking for is `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT
    CustomerID
    , OrderID
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY OrderDate) RunningOrderCount
from #existingtable
```

Answer (score 1):

this line will return you the count over a single year

```
select 
      CustomerID
     , Order ID
     , count(*) OVER 
            (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY DATEPART(yy,orderDate) ) as year_total
from #customtable
```

It's the same if you use row_number instead of count(*)